# Pause with tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pause

I have the following slide in Beamer where I create a diagram with `tikzpicture` (source below)

[image]

**QUESTION** I would like to sequentially show:

- First: the first bullet point together with the line with the annotations Step 1, Step 2
- Second: the annotation A
- Third: the annotation B
- Fourth: the annotation C
- Fifth: the second and third bullet points

I have tried to use `pause`, `visible`, etc. at the desired points but I always get the error

[image]

Could you advise on how to fix this?

```
    \documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{changepage}
    \usetheme{Madrid}
    \usecolortheme{seahorse}
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
    
    
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Overview}
    \scriptsize
    \begin{itemize}
    \item {\small Steps 1,2}
    \begin{figure}
     \begin{adjustwidth}{0.8cm}{}
        \newlength\yearposx 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.48] % timeline 1990-2010->
        % define coordinates (begin, used, end, arrow)
        \foreach \x in {1990,1996}{
            \pgfmathsetlength\yearposx{(\x-1990)*2.5cm};
            \coordinate (y\x)   at (\yearposx,0);
            \coordinate (y\x t) at (\yearposx,+3pt);
            \coordinate (y\x b) at (\yearposx,-3pt);
        }
        % draw horizontal line with arrow
        \visible<1->{\draw [-] (y1990) -- (y1996);
        % draw ticks
        \foreach \x in {1990,1996}
        \draw (y\x t) -- (y\x b);}
        % annotate
        \foreach \x in {1990}
        \node at (y\x) [below=3pt] {\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
            \text{A} \\[-\jot]\\[-\jot]
            \text{B} \\[-\jot]\\[-\jot]
            \text{C}\\[-\jot]
            \text{C}\\[-\jot]
            \text{C}
            \end{tabular}};
        \foreach \x in {1996}
        \node at (y1996) [below=3pt] {\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
            \text{A} \\[-\jot] \\[-\jot]
            \text{B} \\[-\jot]   \\[-\jot]
            \text{C}\\[-\jot] 
            \text{C}
            \end{tabular}};
        \foreach \x in {1990}
        \node at (y\x) [above=3pt] {{\small {Step 1}}};
        \foreach \x in {1996}
        \node at (y\x) [above=3pt] {{\small {Step 2}}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{adjustwidth}
    \end{figure}
    \vspace{0.7cm}
    \item {\small  Step 3}
    \vspace{0.9cm}
    \item {\small  Step 4}
    
    
    \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: If you move `\newlength\yearposx` before `\begin{frame}`, there is no error. However, introducing a new length here is completely unnecessary, you can just work with macros.

Comment: That is, `\pgfmathsetmacro\yearposx{(\x-1990)*2.5}
        \coordinate (y\x)   at (\yearposx,0);
        \coordinate (y\x t) at (\yearposx,+3pt);
        \coordinate (y\x b) at (\yearposx,-3pt);` will also do.

Comment: Thanks, it still gives me error when I proceed with the macro inside the frame

Comment: Did you remove `\newlength\yearposx`?

Comment: OK, it works now, thanks for the advise